# How to get a specific order with ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

i'm looking to create a bar chart in ggplot which shows pg on the y axis and month_year on the x axis. This is how my data is set out however I also have data for June, August and October in the month_year column

```
A tibble: 367 x 3
   site              month_year    pg
   <chr>             <chr>        <dbl>
 1 ds_laverstock_br_ april_2013   1034.
 2 ds_laverstock_br_ april_2014   1104.
 3 ds_laverstock_br_ april_2015    820.
 4 ds_laverstock_br_ april_2016    567.
 5 ds_laverstock_br_ april_2017    752.
 6 ds_laverstock_br_ april_2018    696.
 7 ds_laverstock_br_ april_2019    377.
 8 ds_laverstock_br_ april_2020    505.
 9 ds_laverstock_br_ april_2021    311.
10 ds_laverstock_br_ april_2022    407.
```

I have created this bar chart with this code

```
p <- ggplot(subset(mesohab_r_file, site %in% "ds_laverstock_br_"), aes(x = month_year, y = pg)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
p + coord_flip()
```

[image]

However, the bars are not in the right order for the seasons (April, June, August, October). I suspect this is because of the way I have my months and years written out in my data. Ideally I would like the individual bars to be in month and year order (e.g. April 2013, June 2013, August 2013, October 2013, April 2014, June 2014....) and to not have a label for every bar and just have one label for each year (April 2013-Oct 2013 would just be labelled 2013) - so I guess the data is grouped in a way but they still have their own individual bars

How do I need to change my code or change my data to be able to show this?

Example code:

```
site <- c("ds_laverstock_br_","ds_laverstock_br_","ds_laverstock_br_","ds_laverstock_br_","ds_laverstock_br_","ds_laverstock_br_","ds_laverstock_br_", "ds_laverstock_br_")
month_year <-c("April_2013","June_2013","August_2013","October_2013","April_2014","June_2014","August_2014","October_2014")
pg <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800)
meso <- data.frame(site, month_year, pg)
```

Comment: Every question on stackoverflow that asks about [tag:ggplot2] and asks to change the order of bars, legend elements, facets, or axis labels is resolved by the use of `factor`, else they are _always_ ordered alphabetically.

Comment: In this case, `meso <- transform(meso, month_year = reorder(month_year, as.Date(paste0("01_", month_year), format="%d_%b_%Y")))` will set them as factors and order them correctly.

Comment: More specifically, `transform(meso, month_year = reorder(month_year, as.Date(paste0("01_", month_year), format="%d_%b_%Y"))) |> subset(site %in% "ds_laverstock_br_") |> ggplot(aes(x = month_year, y = pg)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()`.